# I Can modify a value of an Array in a MongoDB Document but it don't update in the database

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have this Room in a Document in my Mondo DB :

```
{
   assets: { tv: true, pc: true, whiteboard: false, projector: true },
   _id: 5ddbbfbb8bbc7741aca695cc,
   name: 'Room 1',
   floor: '1',
   capacity: 10,
   bookings: [
     {
       isValidated: false,
       _id: 5de6ba92112594491017b169,
       startDate: 2019-12-03T23:00:00.000Z,
       endDate: 2019-12-03T23:00:00.000Z,
       startHour: 2019-12-03T11:00:37.862Z,
       duration: 2019-12-03T02:30:37.862Z,
       company: 'Google',
       user: 5ddbca33fdf0e244c53af1b5
     }
   ],
   __v: 0
 }
```

So I wrote this Function to change the value to true using the id of the Room Document and the _id of the booking to change :

```
router.put('/book/pending/:id/:_id', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params
        const { _id  } = req.params
        if (req.user.isAdmin == true) {
            Room.findByIdAndUpdate(id).then((books) => {
                console.log(books)
                var j = 0
                for (let index = 0; index < books.bookings.length; index++) {
                    if (books.bookings[index].isValidated == false && books.bookings[index]._id == _id) {
                        books.bookings[index].isValidated = true
                        j++
                    }
                }
                console.log(books.bookings)
                res.status(200).json(books)
            })
        } else {
            res.status(400).json("Cannot Change Book")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})
```

So this function give me this output :

```
{
   assets: { tv: true, pc: true, whiteboard: false, projector: true },
   _id: 5ddbbfbb8bbc7741aca695cc,
   name: 'Room 1',
   floor: '1',
   capacity: 10,
   bookings: [
     {
       isValidated: true,
       _id: 5de6ba92112594491017b169,
       startDate: 2019-12-03T23:00:00.000Z,
       endDate: 2019-12-03T23:00:00.000Z,
       startHour: 2019-12-03T11:00:37.862Z,
       duration: 2019-12-03T02:30:37.862Z,
       company: 'Google',
       user: 5ddbca33fdf0e244c53af1b5
     }
   ],
   __v: 0
 }
```

But I don't know how to save the array in the document.
Can Someone help me please :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried with `books.save()` or `Room.save(books)`? Assuming `Room` is a Mongoose class, either of the above should should work.

Comment: It Works !!!!!! I tried it before but I changed Because it was telling me books.save() is not a function and Room.save() is not a function but I think this was because my function was jsut findById and not findById and Update! Thank you bro !